# Loop through each row in a column find a null value and replace in a datatable c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a linq query or another way that will loop through all the rows in a column within a data table.

The data column header is known in advanced. As it loops I want to be able to check for a null value in each cell and if found put a default value in, in the case below it is [dob].

Below is an example of a dataTable, I want to able to loop through the [dob] column and look for the null value and replace it with a default value say 01/01/1901.

```
[firstName],     [lastname],     [dob]
tester,          testerSurname,  null
tester2,         tester2Surname, 25/04/1876



 foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
 {
      if (table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(r => r.IsNull(column)))
      {

      }
```

I have started above but could not find away of getting the value and assigning it to another value but could find the null.

Comment: Can you share your code that you tried..

Comment: Just filter the query for rows having null in the target column. Then simply set the default value and save the data back.

Comment: is that data coming from the database?

Comment: yes but cannot be checked or have a default value before it gets to me, the data set is no that large.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't loop through each row in a column, you would just loop through the rows and check that column for each row in the loop:

```
DataTable dt;
string col = "ColumnIAmCheckingForANullValue";
string def = "My Default Value for NULL";

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[col].ToString())) {
        row[col] = def;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to perform a bulk database update, a Linq query is not the best way to go about it.  You're better off writing a SQL query to perform the update - [the COALESCE operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) will be your friend.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET dob = COALESCE(dob, '1901/01/01')
```

Answer (score 0):

If u r using data table then u can also loop through columns in a row

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {

            foreach (DataColumn clm in table.Columns)
            {
                if (dr[clm] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr[clm] = GetDefaultValueForColumn[clm.ColumnName];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: GetDefaultValueForColumn[clm.ColumnName];
 that should be GetDefaultValueForColumn(clm.ColumnName);

Answer (score 0):

If checking for DBNull, the code from [mikeschuld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142305/loop-through-each-row-in-a-column-find-a-null-value-and-replace-in-a-datatable-c/11142387#11142387) should work:

```
DataTable dt;
string col = "ColumnIAmCheckingForANullValue";
string anotherValue = "My Default Value for NULL";

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    if (row[col] is DBNull) {
        row[col] = anotherValue;
    }
}
```

You can remove NULL from data using query

```
SELECT ISNULL(col, '') FROM MyTable
```

Comment: +1 for the `ISNULL` in your `SELECT`. `COALESCE` is helpful too.

Comment: Please be sure to properly cite sources for the code you are using. I've added a citation to indicate that you drew the first portion from mikeschuld's answer, but please do this in the future when using content from others in your answers.